# Uncaught ReferenceError: txtMaking_F is not defined

Tags: javascript

I use two textbox to sum number but showing error..

```
    <script>
        function getPrice(tMaking, tHandeling, tTotal) {
            var obj_tMaking = document.getElementById(txtMaking_F)
            var obj_tHandeling = document.getElementById(txtHandeling_F)
            var obj_tTotal = document.getElementById(txtTotal_F)
            if (obj_tMaking.value != "" && obj_tHandeling.value != "") {
                obj_tTotal.value = parseInt(obj_tMaking.value) + parseInt(obj_tHandeling.value);
            }
            else {
                obj_tTotal.value = "";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input name="grdView$ctl08$txtMaking_F" type="text" id="grdView_ctl08_txtMaking_F" class="classMaking" onchange="javascript:return getPrice('grdView_ctl08_txtMaking_F','grdView_ctl08_txtHandeling_F','grdView_ctl08_txtTotal_F');" style="width: 60px;" />
    <input name="grdView$ctl08$txtHandeling_F" type="text" id="grdView_ctl08_txtHandeling_F" class="classHandling" onchange="javascript:return getPrice('grdView_ctl08_txtMaking_F','grdView_ctl08_txtHandeling_F','grdView_ctl08_txtTotal_F');" style="width: 60px;" />
    <input name="grdView$ctl08$txtTotal_F" type="text" id="grdView_ctl08_txtTotal_F" class="classTotal" style="width: 100px;" />
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: And what is your question?  Don't you understand the error? It means that the variable `txtMaking_F` is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have typos in your function

```
function getPrice(tMaking, tHandeling, tTotal) {
            var obj_tMaking = document.getElementById(tMaking)
            var obj_tHandeling = document.getElementById(tHandeling)
            var obj_tTotal = document.getElementById(tTotal)
                                   //                   ^  - removed extra "txt" & "_F"

            if (obj_tMaking.value != "" && obj_tHandeling.value != "") {
            obj_tTotal.value = parseInt(obj_tMaking.value) + parseInt(obj_tHandeling.value);
        }
        else {
            obj_tTotal.value = "";
        }
    }
```

I supose you want the values passed to the function to be id's, in that case should have `tMaking`in `var obj_tMaking = document.getElementById(txtMaking_F)` and not `txtMaking_F`. Same for `obj_tHandeling` and `obj_tTotal`.

Comment: @NISAR, its not silly, we all do mistakes. Its nice to have more people looking at the code :)